# Change richTextBox link color

Tags: c#, colors, hyperlink

I have made a simple text editor. But when i type a link in my richTextBox it turns blue.. How do i change the link color? I looked on some other forums, but all that did not work..

this is that code:

```
string str = richTextBox1.Text;

Regex re = new Regex("^((ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/|~/|/)?([\w]+:\w+@)?([a-zA-Z]{1}([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,5}))(:[\d]{1,5})?((/?\w+/)+|/?)(\w+\.[\w]{3,4})?((\?\w+=\w+)?(&\w+=\w+)*)?", RegexOptions.None);

MatchCollection mc = re.Matches(str);

foreach (Match ma in mc)
{
    richTextBox1.Select(ma.Index, ma.Length);
    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Comment: using the example provided above, did you set DetectUrls property to False?

Comment: Aha, well.. Kinda dump i did not see that.. Thanks you very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change link color in RichTextBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061696/change-link-color-in-richtextbox). Actually, this question has the same code of the link.